# Archive repository for Debian Squeeze

Tags: repository, debian, archive

I still use Debian Squeeze, and since this release has been archived (Feb 29, 2016) I use the archives repositories on archive.debian.org

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-archive/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-archive/debian/ squeeze-lts main contrib non-free
```

Since 2 days , I get this error message with aptitude update: (same with apt-get)

```
E: Release file expired, ignoring http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze-lts/Release (invalid since 2d 17h 24                                                                                                                        min 57s)
```

With increasing time of course. I tried many other archives repositories but same error.
I found this workaround:

```
aptitude -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update
```

It works, but I would find a solution without this option. I have no fast possibility to update aptitude parameters on all servers I'm running.

By the way the question is: what is the problem with repositories ? Am I doing something wrong ?

I found no update or news about repositories problem on Debian site/mailing list.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Create a file with setting:

```
echo 'Acquire::Check-Valid-Until "false";' >/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90ignore-release-date
```

The release-files of the repository have an expire date (Valid-until).

See the part in the documentation: https://wiki.debian.org/RepositoryFormat#Date.2CValid-Until

Comment: Yes I will deploy a file, I think that no update will be make on Debian repos.